# Is stupidest a word?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, superlatives

Is the word stupidest grammatically incorrect? I've seen that you have to write "the most stupid," or something like that. But we're taught that stupidest is wrong.

Comment: Long ago the rule was - single-syllable words (fast, tall, hot, fat) could get the -est ending (fastest, tallest, hottest, fattest), and multi-syllable words would use most (important: most important; unruly: most unruly; hateful: most hateful), with at least some exceptions for some two syllable words ending in -y, like happy: happiest or silly: silliest. Another exception was for at least some two-syllable words with emphasis on the first syllable, like stupid. We always said stupidest, and that still sounds better to me than more stupid.

Comment: From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stupid): "**Is stupidest a word?** The word *stupidest* has been in use for hundreds of years; there is nothing wrong with it. *Most stupid* means the same thing, and people who don't like *stupidest* should feel free to use it instead."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "stupidest" is a real word and it is grammatically correct. I only found that out now as I researched this answer.

When I was in elementary school in the 1960's, I was also taught that one had to say:

1. stupid
2. more stupid (comparative)
3. most stupid (superlative)

In recent years, I hear people saying things like, "That's the stupidest thing I ever heard." Or, "Can anything be stupider than that?"

It seemed to me like slang, like people were just too lazy to speak correctly in the vernacular. However, when I looked it up on Google just now, I found the following in [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/is-stupider-a-word/):

> Stupid is a two-syllable adjective, which means you can make its
>   comparative and superlative forms in one of two ways: by adding the
>   corresponding suffix or by adding more or most.

For some two-syllable words, says Grammarly, we put more and most in front of them but for stupid we can use either method.

---

***Comparative***: er: tall, taller; stupid, stupider; more stupid

***Superlative***: est: tall, taller, tallest; stupid, stupider, stupidest; most stupid

---

According to Grammarly:

> Stupider is grammatically correct, it is a real word, and it’s been in
>   use for at least the last two hundred years.
>
> ...
>
> As with stupider, stupidest is perfectly correct and listed as
>   standard in dictionaries.

I'm not going to argue with Grammarly and standard dictionaries. In fact, I like the words *stupider* and *stupidest*. There's just nothing that expresses disgust for lack of thought better than those two words, in my opinion.